# How is 由此 (yóucǐ) = "herefrom" used?

Tags: usage

I see this sign near one of the cafeterias at Nankai University.

[image: 二楼新宇餐厅由此上楼]

It says:

> 二楼新宇餐厅由此上楼
>
> èrlóu xīnyǔ cāntīng yóucǐ shànglóu
>
> second floor Sinew cafeteria; herefrom go upstairs

Where 新宇 (xīnyǔ; Sinew) is the company name.

I'm interested in [由此上楼](http://dict.cn/%E7%94%B1%E6%AD%A4%E4%B8%8A%E6%A5%BC), and particularly how [由此](http://dict.cn/%E7%94%B1%E6%AD%A4) is being used.  I guess it makes sense, effectively meaning "go upstairs here", although I would expect some combination of 这里 (zhèlǐ; here） and 上楼 (shànglóu; go upstairs) to work.  The question [Are there any online resources for learning Chinese 4-character idioms](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/q/1827/8099) and its top answer makes me think it might be something special.

**Question**: How is 由此 used?

I'm seeking just the general idea about how 由此 is used, ideally with some other short examples.  The linked question gives this example

> [由此可见](http://dict.cn/%E7%94%B1%E6%AD%A4%E5%8F%AF%E8%A7%81)
>
> yóucǐ kějiàn
>
> from this, it can be seen that ... (dict.cn translation)

It seems to be quite different usage to 由此上楼, however.

Comment: 由此：１００ sample sentences at jukuu, covering different uses of prep.由,  see grammars on preposition 由，e.g.＂实用现代汉语语法＂（abbr.)(一） **１。**  表示  **处所、时间的起点，事物发展变化的起点或来源**  ，与＂从＂的意思相同。一般来说，用＂从＂的地方都可以用＂由＂。但是＂从＂比＂由＂更加口语化。（１）表示处所的起点：碑身南方有三幅雕，由东方向西的第一幅，是１９１１年的武昌起义（２）表示时间的起点：那部电影是由陈建花第二次去机场迎接妹妹开始的。（３）表示事物发展变化的起点：中国实现现代化，必然要有一个由初级到高级的过程，（４）表示来源：我们由沥青铀矿中提出的物质，它的分解特性与铋相近。 **２。**  引出施事者，表示某事归某人去作。例如：说到底，这种悲哀也许主要应该由我自己负责。**３。**  表示凭借。常用格式：＂由。。。组成＂、＂由。。。构成＂。例如：谈到石油的化学成分，我们可以说，它是由多种物质组成的混合物。＂由＂构成一些  **常用短语** 。如＂由次可知＂、＂由次可见＂、＂由次往前＂。例如：由此可见，我们原先的分析是对的。

Comment: cf.  **从此**  ad. henceforth thereupon therefrom prep. from now on (also 100 samples at jukuu),  由于 (due to, as a result of, thanks to,owing to,since,because)  **由于此**   jukuu samples 1-93，for  **自此** ,(自此以后) after this,since then,  see jukuu samples 1-98,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

由(from)

此(this)

**由此** = **from this**

此 here is an adjective (this),

> Question: How is 由此 used?

由此 (from this) can be used to modify many different omitted object

For Example:

- 由此上楼 = '由此(**處**)上楼' -  'from this (**location**) go upstairs'
- 由此可见 = '由此(**事情**/ **事实**)可见' -  'from this (**affair**/ **fact**) we can see'
- 由此出发 = '由此(**地**/ **点**)出发' - 'set off from this (**place**/ **point**)'
- 由此终结 = '由此(**时**)终结' -  'end from this (**moment**)'

Answer (score 1):

由此上楼 - Go upstairs from here
You may go upstairs (to another place) from here.

由此可见... - We can see that ... therefrom
We get it (a result, or a conclusion, from the foregoing)...

由 means "from" or "by" here, 此 means "this" or "these".